# Ruby split a string using two different delimiters

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to split a string using "+" or "-" as delimiter.

- `test.split(/-/)` will split by "-".
- `test.split(/\+/)` will split by "+".

I need to check for both of them.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a character class and put `+` and `-` inside it.

```
puts test.split(/[+-]/);
```